# using WinSCard library: '__in' was not declared in this scope

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, mingw, winscard

I'm trying to use the WinSCard-library to read data from a Myfare Card.
To do so I link against WinSCard.lib and include the header "WinSCard.h".

from my .pro file:

```
win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/Lib/WinSCard.lib
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Lib/ -lWinSCard
```

from my .cpp file:

```
#include "WinSCard.h"
```

But now I get dozens of errors (337 to be precise) of undefined symbols like '_*in', '*_out', '__reserved' and so on.
I use QtCreator/mingw++ as environment. My guess is, that these are typedefs which are library specific or windows specific.

These errors happen by including the header file, I did not use any of the API-functions yet.

Can anybody give me a hint, what I need to include/link to satisfy the compiler?

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: You'll need to document where this WinSCard.h file came from.  Don't just copy it from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the sal.h header solved these issues.

Comment: For completeness: I tried first an example code with the VisualStudio Express, so I had the "Microsoft SDKs\Windows\V7.0a" directory at hand. The sal.h I found in the "Visual Studio Express 10.0\VC\crt\" directory. I will have to check if there is a special SDK out there, or if I need to get a license from Microsoft.